# InnerText when using XMLDocument removing carriage returns?

Tags: c#, text, xpath, innertext

I am attempting to figure out why some text apparently doesn't have any carriage returns in it, even though it looks like it does.  I am wondering if calling innerText when Xpath'ing through a XmlDocument (in .net 4.0) strips carriage returns or other characters.  Probably not, But at this point I looking for anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown any code, so it's hard to know where the data came from. By default, insignificant whitespace is *not* preserved when loading an `XmlDocument`. You might want to try setting [`XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx) to true before loading.

If that doesn't help, please post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Well, I am a little hesitant to put my code online, and I am just trying to smoke out possible causes of this problem.

Comment: @DmainEvent: You don't need to put your *real* code online. You need to post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. The shorter the better!

Answer (score 2):

What's the `xml:space` on the element? If you need to force it to be preserve whitespace other than significant whitespace, then you can set `PreserveWhitespace` to `true` before calling `Load` or `LoadXML`.

Be cautions with this though as in most cases the person writing the XML will expect the normal XML rules for whitespace to be followed. Even worse, if you get a "works for me" by using the non-standard rules that `PreserveWhitespace` uses, there's no reason you should expect anyone else to parse it as you intend.